# Remove Pair from TJsonObject

Tags: c++, json, delphi, c++builder

```
{
  "Test":{
    "A":{
      "ins":{
        "type":"pac",
        "id":{
          "values":{
            "test_number":"156764589",
            "val":"abcde",
            "val_2":"gggg",
            "val_3":"jjjj"
          },
          "verif":{
          },
          "bool":"INSTR"
        }
      }
    },
    "resp":{
      "image":"include"
    },
    "op":{
      "id":{
        "meth":"def"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am logging a http request been sent & need to remove an element from a `TJsonObject` for privacy. However when I attempt to remove key and log it still persists

```
TJSONObject *obj = (TJSONObject*) TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(TEncoding::UTF8->GetString(id_http_wrap.msg));
obj->RemovePair("Test.A.ins.type.id.values.test_number");
```

Comment: That route makes no sense - you can only mean `"Test.A.ins.id.values.test_number"`.

Comment: @AmigoJack Yes apologies that was a typo when creating question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your path is wrong. `type` is not in the path down to `test_number`. The correct one would have been:

```
obj->RemovePair("Test.A.ins.id.values.test_number");
```

But as far as I know, that can't be parsed by `RemovePair`. You'll have to use [`FindValue`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.JSON.TJSONValue.FindValue):

```
// Cast helper:
TJSONObject* ToTJSONObject(TJSONValue* v) {
    auto obj = dynamic_cast<TJSONObject*>(v);
    if(!obj) throw Exception("v is not a TJSONObject");
    return obj;
}

auto obj = ToTJSONObject(TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(...));

TJSONPair* removed =
    ToTJSONObject(obj->FindValue("Test.A.ins.id.values"))->RemovePair("test_number");

if(removed) {
    // successfully removed:         removed->ToString()
    // the resulting JSON document:  obj->ToString()
}
```

Comment: I am getting a `E2034 Cannot convert 'TJSONPair *' to 'TJSONObject *'` on that line

Comment: @user2020 Then I think you've done something between `TJSONObject* obj = ParseJSONValue(...);` and my line. If you have a `TJSONObject*` the above should work. It does for me.

Comment: @user2020 Did you perhaps use the `Get` method between parsning and using my suggestion? If so, that's the problem. It returns a `TJSONPair*`. Use `GetValue` that returns a `TJSONValue*` instead.

Comment: I am doing the following `TJSONObject *new_obj = ToObject(obj->FindValue("Test.A.ins.id.values"))->RemovePair("test_number");` so I can print using `new_obj.ToString()`. And that is resulting in that error message

Comment: @user2020 `RemovePair` returns a pointer to the removed `TJSONPair`. If you instead do `obj->ToString()` you'll see your original JSON data but without the removed `test_number`

Comment: @user2020 If you actually want to look at the removed data, don't try to cast the returned value to a `TJSONObject*`. Just do `TJSONPair* jpair = ToObject(obj->FindValue("Test.A.ins.id.values"))->RemovePair("test_number");` and look at it with `jpair->ToString();`

Comment: @user2020 I added more to the answer that may help

Comment: thanks that clears it up for me. My misunderstanding.

Comment: @user2020 You're welcome! Glad it worked out!

Comment: On a side note, I would suggest changing `ToTJSONObject()` to use `dynamic_cast` instead: `TJSONObject* ToTJSONObject(TJSONValue* v) { TJSONObject *obj = dynamic_cast<TJSONObject*>(v); if (!obj) throw Exception("v is not a TJSONObject"); return obj; }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I agree. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
implementation

uses
  System.IOUtils, System.JSON;

procedure DoSomeJSONStuff;
var
  jsonstr: string;
  jo, jochild: TJSONObject;
begin
  jsonstr := TFile.ReadAllText('C:\Temp\example.json', TEncoding.UTF8);
  jo := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(jsonstr) as TJSONObject;
  if (jo <> nil) then begin
    try
      jochild := ((((jo.GetValue('Test') as TJSONObject).GetValue('A') as TJSONObject).GetValue('ins') as TJSONObject).GetValue('id') as TJSONObject).GetValue('values') as TJSONObject;
      jochild.RemovePair('test_number');
      TFile.WriteAllText('C:\Temp\example_changed.json', jo.ToString, TEncoding.UTF8);
    finally
      jo.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Keep in mind, that TFile.ReadAllText and WriteAllText with UTF-8 encoding is actually UTF-8-BOM.

Of course, you can format the code better.

Comment: Nice trick if lack of explanation and comments regarding the actual question was intended.

Answer (score 0):

In kbmMW one could do like this:

```
const JSON: string =
'{'+
'  "Test":{'+
'    "A":{'+
'      "ins":{'+
'        "type":"pac",'+
'        "id":{'+
'          "values":{'+
'            "test_number":"156764589",'+
'            "val":"abcde",'+
'            "val_2":"gggg",'+
'            "val_3":"jjjj"'+
'          },'+
'          "verif":{'+
'          },'+
'          "bool":"INSTR"'+
'        }'+
'      }'+
'    },'+
'    "resp":{'+
'      "image":"include"'+
'    },'+
'    "op":{'+
'      "id":{'+
'        "meth":"def"'+
'      }'+
'    }'+
'  }'+
'}';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   str:TkbmMWJSONStreamer;
   js,o:TkbmMWONCustomObject;
begin
     str:=TkbmMWJSONStreamer.Create;
     try
        js:=str.LoadFromUTF16String(JSON);
        o:=js.Path('Test/A/ins/id/values');
        if o.IsObject then
           TkbmMWONObject(o).Remove('test_number');
        Memo1.Lines.DelimitedText:=JSON;
        Memo2.Lines.DelimitedText:=str.SaveToUTF16String(js);
     finally
        str.Free;
     end;
end;
```